# Can I use $angular timeout in a return statement?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Parse data, and I want to return the variable ParseUserArray. But just after it passing by the success promise. I was wondering how can I do that.

```
var UserWs = angular.module('UserWs', []);
    
    UserWs.service('UserWsService', ['parseInit', function(parseInit){
        var service = this;
            this.getUserAtParse = function(id){
                var user = Parse.Object.extend("User");
                var query = new Parse.Query(user);
                  var parseUserArray = [];
                    query.find({
                        success: function(anUser) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < anUser.length; i++) {
                                var newUser = new User(anUser[i]);
                                parseUserArray.push(newUser);
                            }
                            console.log(parseUserArray);
                             
                        }

                    });
                    
                    var User =function(anUser){
                        this.id = anUser.id;
                        this.name = anUser.get("name");
                        this.email = anUser.get("username");
                        this.company = anUser.get("company");
                    }
            return parseUserArray;
                    
                    
                };
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: but i am not using ajax

Comment: Why don't wrap the call to `UserWsService.getUserAtParse` inside `$timeout`?

Comment: i don't think that this will works, because i guess the function will takes longer to start, but inside will be the same thing, but i don't know, i will try! thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `promise` for this -  `$q` service

```
var UserWs = angular.module('UserWs', []);

UserWs.service('UserWsService', ['$q', 'parseInit', function($q, parseInit) {
  var service = this;
  this.getUserAtParse = function(id) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    var user = Parse.Object.extend("User");
    var query = new Parse.Query(user);
    var parseUserArray = [];
    query.find({
      success: function(anUser) {
        for (var i = 0; i < anUser.length; i++) {
          var newUser = new User(anUser[i]);
          parseUserArray.push(newUser);
        }
        console.log(parseUserArray);
        defer.resolve(parseUserArray);
      }

    });

    var User = function(anUser) {
      this.id = anUser.id;
      this.name = anUser.get("name");
      this.email = anUser.get("username");
      this.company = anUser.get("company");
    }
    return defer.promise;
  }
}]);

UserWs.controller('sampleCtrl', ['$scope', 'UserWsService', function($scope, UserWsService) {
  UserWsService.getUserAtParse(SOME_ID).then(function(resultArray) {
    //logic here
  });
}]);
```

Comment: i really didn't know that this exists hahaha, i will have a look at documentation and try your solution too! Thanks